# c++ can't put data into vector

Tags: c++, vector, push-back

I have a data-structure and a processor-class for the data, the data is stacked without pointers for faster SIMD processing:

```
struct trajectory_data {
    float position[3];
    float velocity[3];
    float acceleration[3];
    ...
};

class trajectory_processor{
private:
    vector<trajectory_data> tdata;
    vector<trajectory_data> default_data;
    ...
};
```

But I fail to actually add a data-set to the vector, neither of those work:

```
trajectory_processor::trajectory_processor(){

    // gives error: no match for ‘operator=’ in ...
    trajectory_data d0();
    default_data[0] = d0;

    // gives error: no matching function for call to
    // ‘std::vector<trajectory_data>::push_back(trajectory_data (&)())
    trajectory_data d1();
    default_data.push_back(d1);
};
```

According to [push_back reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/push_back/) and [C++ vector push_back](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7382090/c-vector-push-back) I assumed this should be easy, but even after several google searches I just can't find any answer.

This project involves cross-coding in html/javascript and I seem to hit a wall like this one every time I switch back to c++, it starts wearing on my nerves.

Comment: I may be wrong here, but I think this is a subtle C++ parsing error with the line trajectory_data d0();. This is being interpreted as a function declaration with the function being called d0 and returning a trajectory_data. Try and remove the ().

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You seem to be a victim of the [Most Vexing Parse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse).  Basically, the line

```
trajectory_data d1();
```

is actually declaring a function d1 that takes no argument and returns a `trajectory_data` object.

Changing it to

```
trajectory_data d1;
```

should fix your problem, same for `d0`.  The default constructor will be called anyways, no need for the `()`.

Comment: Although, if you're relying on value-initialisation, you'll need to change it to `trajectory_data d1 = trajectory_data();` or `trajectory_data d1 {};` if you can use C++11.

Comment: Thanks, guess I shouldn't try that hard after only four hours of sleep. You just prevented a coder from giving up c++ and skipping to node.js :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this: `default_data.push_back(trajectory_data());`

Answer (score 0):

Change `trajectory_data d0();` to `trajectory_data d0;`

The first declares a function `d0` that takes no arguments and returns `trajectory_data`.
The second explicitly and clearly creates an instance of `trajectory_data` called `d0`.

This also applies to `trajectory_data d1();`