# Segmentation fault when push_back to vector c++

Tags: c++

I am trying to append a blank object to a list using the `push_back` method.

main.cpp

```
    vector<FacialMemory> facial_memory;

    printf("2\n");

    // Add people face memories based on number of sections
    for (int i = 0; i < QuadrantDict::getMaxFaceAreas(); i++)
    {
            printf("i %d\n", i);
            FacialMemory n_fm;
            facial_memory.push_back(n_fm);  // NOTE: Breaks here
    }
```

At the `push_back` method call, the program crashes with a segmentation fault. I have looked around at similar questions and they point to the solution I have here. I have also tried to pass `FacialMemory()` into the push_back call but still the same issue.

The FacialMemory class is defined as such:
FacialMemory.h

```
class FacialMemory
{
private:
        vector<FaceData> face_memory;
public:
        FacialMemory();
        ~FacialMemory();
        void pushData(FaceData face);
        bool isEmpty();
        vector<FaceData> getFaces();
        FaceData getRecent();
};
```

Constructor and destructor

```
FacialMemory::FacialMemory()
{
}


FacialMemory::~FacialMemory()
{
       delete[] & face_memory;
}
```

Comment: What's in your FacialMemory class' constructor? Also your code is inefficient because you're copying objects everywhere. Consider using move semantics or heap-allocated objects.

Comment: Ok, I've added the constructor and destructor for the FacialMemory

Comment: Why do you delete `face_memory` with `delete []` ?

Comment: Ok, removing the `delete[]` line fixes the error. Still not sure why though?

Comment: You would likely have a similar crash even if you removed the `facial_memory.push_back(n_fm);` statement since each time through the loop the destructor for `n_fm` is called.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

When you `push_back` an item into a `vector`, the item is copied. Sometimes this triggers more work as the `vector` is resized: Its current contents are copied, and the now-copied elements that used to belong to the `vector` are destroyed. destruction invokes the destructor.

Unfortunately, `FacialMemory`'s destructor contains a fatal error:

```
FacialMemory::~FacialMemory()
{
       delete[] & face_memory; <<== right here
}
```

It tries to `delete[]` data that was not allocated by `new[]`, and whatever is managing the program's memory threw a fit because the expected book-keeping structures that keep track of dynamically allocated storage (memory allocated with `new` or with `new[]`) for the storage being returned were not found or not correct.

Further, `face_memory` is a `std::vector`, an object designed to look after its memory for you. You can create, copy, resize, and delete a `vector` without any intervention in most cases. The most notable counter case is a `vector` of pointers where you may have to release the pointed-at data when removing the pointer from the `vector`.

The solution is to do nothing in the `FacialMemory` class destructor. In fact, the [Rule of Zero](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three) recommends that you not have a destructor at all because `FacialMemory` has no members or resources that require special handling. The compiler will generate the destructor for you with approximately zero chance of a mistake being made.

While reading the link for the Rule of Zero, pay attention to the Rules of Three and Five because they handle the cases where a class does require special handling and outline the minimum handling you should provide.

Comment: I have this exact issue but if I remove the destructor or add a copy constructor and copy assignment I still have the same problem.

Comment: @WilliamLohan Sounds different enough to be worth a new question.. At the very least, I'd need to see code to be of much help, and code and comments don't mix well.

Comment: I found a work around, I don't understand why but pointerToObject->appendChild(pointerToChild) threw a segment fault but valueOfObject.appendChild(pointerToChild) worked (where appendChild calls vector.push_back() ) but the code has completely changed to so I'd have nothing to make a new question with.

Comment: Could be that as `vector`s are resized pointers to elements in the `vector` are rendered invalid. No way to say anything with certainty though.

Answer (score 1):

One of the reason to occur Segmentation fault is when ever you access a memory part which is invalid and In your program you are deallocating memory(**delete** keyword in your destructor) which is not allocated by **new** keyword.

Answer (score -5):

Please refer to [vector-push-back](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7382090/c-vector-push-back)

Try adding a meaningful copy constructor to `FacialMemory` class